# Why is this statement false?

Tags: data-structures, big-o

The function 4n + 6 can be said to belong to O(n³).I want to know why is this false. I am new to data structure. I will be really glad if someone can explain it to me.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for help with *programming*, not computer science homework.

Comment: I found questions with big oh here thats why I asked :)

Comment: Who says it's a wrong statement?

Comment: I am an online course. In the quiz part it shows you the answers.

Comment: It's a valid statement. Of course most university courses are asking which is the least-growing function for bounding and they want to hear O(n) in this case. But the statement is still true.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this question is off-topic on StackOverflow, but I'll answer it anyway:

Big-O is an upper bound, not a tight bound.  If you have ten dollars in your pocket and tell your friend "I have an amount of money in my pocket, and it's no more than a million dollars", you're telling the truth, but you're not giving them terribly accurate information.

Likewise, the function `f(n) = 4n + 6` is technically in O(n^3); it's also in O(n^2), O(2^n), and O(n!), but the most accurate upper bound is O(n).

Comment: @FarhaNashra Govinds answer is correct. But if you want to pursue the formal route, check the formal definition (right part of the table under *Family of Bachmann–Landau notations*) [at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family).

Comment: If you're simply multiplying a number by 4 and then adding 6, it's O(1).

Comment: @JacobG. The OP's question was about which order of asymptotic growth  the mathematical function `4n + 6` is in, not how many steps it takes to compute "4 * n + 6" in a computer program.

Comment: @GovindParmar How do you know?

Comment: @JacobG. It's obvious in this setting (asymptotic algorithmic analysis). (It's sad what one has to read at all those complexity-related questions)

Comment: I don't believe it is, OP should specify.